# How to reduce duplications in styles - control template with triggers (xaml)

Tags: wpf, xaml

The problem is my styles file is 10k lines abomination because of duplications.

For example I have a `ButtonScaleMinus` style that is already based on `AllButtons` but I can not separete ControlTemplate same way. There are alot of triggers that are bound to border name.

The only difference is actually content of `<Border x:Name='ElementBorder'...` So everything same, only small chunk of code will vary.

```
<Style x:Key='ButtonScaleMinus'
       TargetType='Button'
       BasedOn='{StaticResource AllButtons}'>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name='ElementBorder'
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="0"
                        BorderBrush='{StaticResource border1}'
                        Background='{StaticResource MenuButtonGradient}'>
                    <Viewbox Margin='10'
                             x:Name='ViewBox'
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Path Data='M416 208H32c-17.67 0-32 14.33-32 32v32c0 17.67 14.33 32 32 32h384c17.67 0 32-14.33 32-32v-32c0-17.67-14.33-32-32-32z'
                              Fill='White'
                              Stroke='White'
                              x:Name='faImage'/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                Value="0.2" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value='LightGray' />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ElementBorder"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value='{StaticResource DefaultButtonOverBackground}' />
                        <Setter Property="Cursor"
                                Value='Hand' />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ElementBorder"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value='{StaticResource DefaultButtonPressedBackground}' />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Is there any way to reduce code above to something like this:

```
<Style x:Key='ButtonScaleMinus'
   TargetType='Button'
   BasedOn='{StaticResource AllButtons}'>
   [different Border content]
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no content of that button, hence you've got a template for every icon you will use.

That's a mistake.

You can simplify what you have there anyhow, set the path to stretch and it will fill it's container, so you can lose the viewbox.

Essentially you want the properties of your path - a Geometry ( the data for the path ), fill, stoke and anything else you use in other templates.

Either.

Create an IconButton or something, inheriting Button and add dependency properties for those properties.

Or

A class which attaches those dependency properties.

Move all your geometries into a resource dictionary and give them keys.

Here's an example

```
<Geometry x:Key="FlowRight">
    M1.265625,12.9837493896484L95.625,50.7181243896484 1.265625,88.5462493896484 24.375,50.7181243896484 1.265625,12.9837493896484z
</Geometry>
```

You can then use that as a StaticResource.

You can then have one IconButton Template.
Define styles set the geometry and brushes if you have a lot of (say) plus icon buttons.

Or

You can just set or bind those properties directly on a Button/IconButton that uses your template.

Or

Do both. Set one or two properties to over-ride those in a common style.

Maybe that isn't flexible enough for what you want to do.

You can use a ContentControl and Styles/Templates for that to define content within your templates.

You can add a ContentPresenter to your template and whatever you set the content of your button to will appear in that.

Comment: I was able to solve problem with `<ContentPresenter/>` - you can supply it, for example, with `<Path>` or `<StackPanel>` pretty much anything you may need.